# Обработчик Javascript

Tags: javascript, парсер

Господа, подскажите где почитать реализацию идеи:

Есть форма в которую вбивается url определенного сайта, на сайте (который вбили в форму) нужно найти конкретный div и вытащить из него содержимое.

Comment: Давайте так, есть страница https://www.copart.com/lot/48812719

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
   url:'https://www.copart.com/lot/48812719',
   type:'GET',
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
       $('#btnhtml5rocks').html($(data).find('.title').html());
   }
});
 });

Comment: есть код который не работаем потому что CORS, мне нужно просто вытянуть значение span.title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java-script парсеры, посмотрите и выберите наиболее удобный Вам:

PhantomJS
CasperJS
SlimerJS
Zombie.js

Comment: Есть вариант чего-нибудь проще? Библиотеку подкинул и в бой?

Comment: Так библиотеки и задуманы для упрощения парсинга - в мануалах к ним достаточно подробно описываются варианты возможного использования - а реализации уже разные есть варианты. Что предлагать без конретного вопроса сложно - это будет испорченный телефон передачи того же манула/инструкции, да еще в расплывчатом применении - шарообразный конь в вакууме.

Comment: Я с node.js вообще не дружу, есть вариант допустим как с JQuery просто в хидере подключить библиотеку?

Comment: Я понял как вопрос задать!)

Comment: Как с помощью AJAX просто скачать текст другой страницы

Comment: Создайте отдельный вопрос - это будет правильно и результат будет поширше и по-быстрее. И уточните там сразу - Вам обязательно через js, или просто нужно решение задачи - это значительно увеличит вариативность возможных решений.